# How do I select this element with Python Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm trying to click a link if it contains this string somewhere in its html. Here is the HTML:

```
        <span class="_3A9bf_kZ6VBA2VBRND5gvf">r/smashbros</span>
```

I'm trying to click the link if it contains the word "smash" somewhere in the element, how would I go about this? I know I can easily do

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3A9bf_kZ6VBA2VBRND5gvf").click()
```

I'm trying to find a way more dynamic way to find the element, since there is a chance that the element might not be there.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at xpath's contains method:
https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html#1

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'smash')]")
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print('No Such Element found')
```